# Find all places a method is used in my views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, reflection

Sprinkled throughout my views I make calls to a method that translates text into a user's preferred language. For example:

```
@Translate("Translate this for me")
```

Now I want to find every call to this method so that I can compile a list of all the text that needs to be translated in my MVC project.

I've used reflection before to access all of my controllers and action methods, but how can I access the views and the method calls therein? Or is there another way to do this without using reflection? Perhaps the razor engine can be called upon to help with this somehow?

**EDIT:**
The "Translate" method is in a BaseWebViewPage that all my views inherent from

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your comments, I hadn't thought of using 'find' in Visual Studio for this - it's a really practical answer, much appreciated. Although, while we're here, I wonder if there is a programmatic way to do this?

Comment: Does `right click + Find all references` do what you want?

Comment: @Corak, It will not show references from views.

Comment: @Dean, One way to achieve it is change the function name. i.e. change name of Translate to Translate1 and in error list you will get all references of Translate.

Comment: Don't know of another built in way. You might have to resort to `ctrl + shift + F` and search for `Translate(`. -- Or change the function name, like @makwana.a suggests.